# run test with log by name of log in class

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to create a test for the logger in my class.
Class example:

```
     public class Audit{
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Audit.class);
        private static final Logger ERROR_LOG  = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ERROR");
        public static final Logger DEBUG_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("DEBUG");

service.... {
}

}
```

Test that I'm trying to run, a test with class name, and I'm getting the main log but not getting the debug/ error log:

```
    @Test
void testFailure() {
    
    Logger auditFailureLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Audit.class);
    ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
    listAppender.start();
    auditFailureLogger.addAppender(listAppender);

    audit.service(info);

    List<ILoggingEvent> logsList = listAppender.list;

    assertNotNull(logsList.get(0).getFormattedMessage());
}
```

If I'm running this test, with the logger name (not class name), I'm getting an empty list:

```
  @Test
void testFailure() {
    
    Logger auditFailureLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("ERROR");
    ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
    listAppender.start();
    auditFailureLogger.addAppender(listAppender);

    audit.service(info);

    List<ILoggingEvent> logsList = listAppender.list;

    assertNotNull(logsList.get(0).getFormattedMessage());
}
```

How can I get the log by name, not by class in test?

Comment: Is this related to Log4j? Looks like SLF4J + Logback to me.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing, I was able to run the test:

```
      @Test
void testFailure() {
    
    Logger auditFailureLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("ERROR");
    ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
    listAppender.start();
    auditFailureLogger.addAppender(listAppender);

    audit.service(info);

    List<ILoggingEvent> logsList = listAppender.list;

    assertNotNull(logsList.get(0).getFormattedMessage());
}
```

I've added the logback.xml file  to the test resources

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration debug="true" scan="false">


  <!-- ============================================== -->
  <!-- Append messages to the failure audit  log file -->
  <!-- ============================================== -->
  <appender name="AUDIT_FAILURE_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>TEST  %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  
  <logger additivity="false" level="ALL" name="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="AUDIT_FAILURE_FILE" />
  </logger>


</configuration>
```